# How to delete an element from an array without using built-in function's in php?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i delete an element from an array without using built-in functions in php ?
But php doesn't have any keyword like delete or remove in it.
can anyone help me ?

Comment: No AFAIK you have to use unset() or array_splice(). What's the problem with using functions, exactly?

Comment: No built-in functions should be used ?

Comment: Why not, exactly? It doesn't really make sense. Just use the correct tool for the job. In this case, that's the ready-made function. Have you been given this as a homework or something?

Comment: Unset is the fastest way and this is a language construct and not a function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so from what I can see there is no logical way to do this and why do you want to do this? PHP was built with these functions for a reason and that's why we all use them.

I recommend you use the following

- Use `unset()` Function to Delete an Element From an Array in PHP
- Use `array_splice()` Function to Delete an Element From an Array in PHP
- Use `array_diff()` Function to Delete an Element From an
  Array in PHP

`unset()`

```
<?php
//Declare the array
$flowers = array(
                "Rose",
                "Lili",
                "Jasmine",
                "Hibiscus",
                "Tulip",
                "Sun Flower",
                "Daffodil",
                "Daisy");

unset($flowers[1]);
echo "The array is:\n";
print_r($flowers);
?>
```

This function can delete one value at a time. The name of the array along with the element index ($flowers[1]) is passed as a parameter. This function does not change the index values. The index values remain the same as they were before.

`array_splice()`

```
<?php
//Declare the array
$flowers = array(
                "Rose",
                "Lili",
                "Jasmine",
                "Hibiscus",
                "Tulip",
                "Sun Flower",
                "Daffodil",
                "Daisy");

array_splice($flowers, 4, 3);
echo "The array is:\n";
print_r($flowers);
?>
```

The array $flowers is passed as a parameter to this function along with the starting index 4 and the number of elements we want to delete-3. In this way, we can delete multiple elements from an array.

`array_diff()`

```
<?php
//Declare the array
$flowers = array(
                "Rose",
                "Lili",
                "Jasmine",
                "Hibiscus",
                "Tulip",
                "Sun Flower",
                "Daffodil",
                "Daisy");

$flowers = array_diff($flowers, array("Rose","Lili"));
echo "The array is:\n";
print_r($flowers);
?>
```

Here, the first array that we have passed is $flowers and the second array contains the elements that we want to delete from $flowers. This function does not change the indexes of the elements of the array.